# С# PictureButton + image

Tags: c#

Дико извеняюсь..Что задаю такой простой вопрос и так часто т.к. в гугле не нашёл.
Нужно чтобы при имеющейся ссылке на изоображение можно было его вывести в PictureButton.
Тоесть схема такая.

1. Есть ссылка.
2. Есть PictureButton
3. Нажимем на кнопку.
4. Картинка появляется в PictureButton.

Как должен выглядеть код?Какие словари добавить?

Comment: Благодарю помогло! не посоветуете ли сайт для справки?
Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: [**MSDN**][1]

@WebStyle, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w0x726c2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинку на кнопку можно добавить вот так:

```
string imageUrl = "http://адрес/вашей/картинки.png";
вашаКнопкаНаКоторойДолжнаБытьКартинка.Image =
    new Bitmap(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(imageUrl)
                                                .GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```